# How to prevent redirect in .htaccess rule rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.getshoutbox.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.getshoutbox\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.getshoutbox.com/test.php?id=%1 [L,NC]
```

These rules work fine, except I got redirect to:

```
http://www.getshoutbox.com/test.php?id=X
```

How to revert that and stay on:

```
http://X.getshoutbox.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your rule is that you were using the full domain with `WWW` instead of just internally redirecting it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# do nothing avoid loop
RewriteRule ^test.php$ - [L]

# if domain is not www.yourdomain.com or yourdomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?getshoutbox\.com$ [NC]
# then get the subdomain with ([^\.]+)?\.yourdomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)?\.getshoutbox\.com$ [NC]
# use the result below
RewriteRule ^ test.php?id=%1 [NC,L]
```

Since we already know we are not on `www.yourdomain.com` or `yourdomain.com`, catch the subdomain and pass it down using `%1` as `id` and remove the `http://www.getshoutbox.com/` as it is not required in this case.